# Return distinct results that appear more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
    ID  Site
    2   NULL
    2   32
    3   6
    4   7
    8   12
    8   13
    9   14
    9   14
```

Result should be:

```
    ID  Site
    2   NULL
    2   32
    8   12
    8   13
```

Note that the result find unique combinations of ID and Site that repeat more than once for a given ID.

I did the following query but does not return the result:

```
 select  distinct id, site
 from Table1  
 group by id, site
 having count(*) > 1
 order by id
```

Comment: Try with nasted select. Fistly to select those who appears more then one in table, and from result of that select to select with distinct.

Comment: Why does (9,14) not appear in your result? The 9 repeats twice.

Comment: because (9, 14) does not appear *distinct* I think @EdmCoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ID,
   site
FROM table1
WHERE ID IN (
   SELECT ID
   FROM (
      SELECT ID ,site
      FROM table1 
      GROUP BY ID ,site
   ) x
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING count(*)>1
)
```

See: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=931766218059a48489c5e148fc4e9a17)

- The `SELECT ID, site FROM table1 GROUP BY ID, site` will select the distinct values.
- Then, using `HAVING count(*) > 1`, only the IDs that appear more than once are filtered.

P.S. You should try to avoid using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in one query. It makes life so much more complicated when you do that ...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to do the `select distinct` in a CTE, then use the `count` window function to get the desired result:

```
with u as (
    select distinct *
    from Table1
), v as (
    select *
        , count(*) over(partition by ID) as cnt
    from u
)
select ID, Site
from v
where cnt > 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85087768be683e42d9e620ec82492c31)